# Introducing smart pointers into a legacy project

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm changing some legacy code so that is uses smart pointers.

Our projects pre-date boost and so we have an existing intrusive smart pointer class (see below for API).

I want to remove explicit calls to `delete` for these types, so what is the best way to find them?

For example:

```
class A : public RefCount // RefCount added to manage lifetime
{
  // ...
};
// typedef A * APtr;  => Previous implementation
typedef SPtr<A> APtr;

void deleteObjects (APtr a)
{
  delete a;      // Want to find this (ideally with compile error)
}
```

All types that are to be used with the smart pointer derive from a base class that keeps a reference count, and it is this class that should be responsible for deleting the object when the count reaches zero.

I've added what I'm doing today as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510312/introducing-smart-pointers-into-a-legacy-project/4510414#4510414), however, the approach doesn't work for calls to delete in hierarchies.  I am looking for a complete solution that catches any explicit call to delete (other than the one from the RefCount member).

The smart pointer class has the following members:

```
template <typename B>
class SPtr
{
public:
  // Ctor
  SPtr () throw ();
  SPtr (B * b) throw ();
  SPtr (const SPtr & bptr) throw ();

  // Copy Asgn      
  SPtr & operator = (B * b);
  SPtr & operator = (const SPtr & bptr);

  // Dtor
  ~SPtr () throw ();


  // Access
  bool isSet () const;

  B * pointer () const;
  B * operator -> () const;
  B & operator * () const;
  operator void const * () const;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `operator void const * () const;` in your smart pointer class and that should do it. Implicit conversions from smart pointer to raw pointer generally hide so many problems it's not worth implementing.

Even with the conversion operator I still got a warning in g++ with the code as posted.

Comment: This isn't really an option.  There's a lot of code dependent on the current API.

Comment: Don't try to do it all at once. Convert one raw pointer to smart and fix up the cases with calls to `.pointer()` before moving on to the next one. You may want to use two separate smart pointer classes to help the migration. You'll probably find more than just bogus deletes in the process. Also do consider how much time you'll spend finding bugs in the code in the years to come as compared to removing the implicit conversion and fixing them all now up front.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, this looks to be the only way I can do this completely reliably.

Answer (score 2):

Make a destructor of template class `SPtr` private. This will result in an error calling `delete a;` where a is of type `SPtr<T>` where T is arbitrary type.

Another solution would be to overload `delete` and `delete[]` operators and make them private. In that case, you still could create class on stack, but calling a delete will result in error. For example:

```
class MyClass {
private:
  void operator delete(void *p);
  void operator delete[](void *p);
};
```

Comment: That would mean we cannot declare any SPtr<T> types on the stack?  For example:  SPtr<A> a; // compile error ~SPtr<A> in accessible

Comment: @Richard Corden: Correct. Vlad's technique is used to FIND things by making the compiler into your search engine. You introduce a situation where delete will produce a compile time error. Then it's up to you to actually modify the code - the compiler is just giving you a list of places you need to change.

Comment: @Michael:  It finds all local objects as well as explicit calls to delete.  The signal to noise will be huge.

Comment: @Vlad: Your second solution is more or less what I've been doing (see my answer).

Comment: @Richard: The code listing you have provided is not full. Basically, in your case, when you call delete on SPtr instance, it calls delete on constant void pointer. If that is a real code, then you have big problems. If you could post minimal working example, I can suggest something better and more realistic.

Comment: @Vlad:  The key point here is that it is the RefCount base class that ultimately is allowed to delete the object.  The SPtr class is responsible for calling two members in RefCount, `RefCount::addRef` and `RefCount::subRef`.  If `subRef` detects that the references has reached 0, it then deletes the object.  I'll work on producing a small example that shows what's happening.

Comment: @Vlad:  In trying to come up with an example - I now think Mark B's answer is pretty much spot on.

Answer (score 1):

A technique that catches cases except those from within the hierarchy is to temporarily use placement new and delete:

```
class A : public RefCount
{
public:
  static void * operator new (size_t, size_t = 0);
  static void operator delete (void *, size_t);

protected:
  static void operator delete (void *);
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  ~B ()
  {
    // requires 'operator delete(void*)' be accessible
  }

private:
  SPtr<A> m_a;
};
```

It is necessary to use placement new, as the `operator delete` for a call to `operator new` must be accessible when allocating an object (in case an exception is thrown).  Therefore, in order to be able to call `new A` we need both an `operator new` and and `operator delete`.

```
SPtr<A> m_a = new A;  // requires matching `operator new` and `operator delete`
```

The rules in the standard mean that the `operator delete` that's called for this situation matches the `operator new`, and so the additional default parameter requires that `operator delete(void*, size_t)` be accessible when allocating and not `operator delete(void*)`.

The drawback as shown in the example, however, is that derived classes still require that `operator delete(void*)` be accessible.

This is a temporary change only, once all calls to delete have been found and removed, the overloads should be removed.